# WFS_CMD_IDC_READ_RAW_DATA always returns WFS_EXEE_IDC_INVALIDMEDIA event in my application

Tags: cen-xfs

I'm creating an application using CEN/XFS API and i'm using PIN and IDC modules.

In the first step(after startup/open/register), i want to let user insert it's id-card. So i call `WFS_CMD_IDC_READ_RAW_DATA` with `WFSAsyncExecute` command. After this command completed(after: `Messages WFS_EXECUTE_COMPLETE` event), i expect to have `WFS_EXEE_IDC_MEDIAINSERTED` event, but i always get `WFS_EXEE_IDC_INVALIDMEDIA` in my application. What's going on?

Edit: To ensure that the card reader doesn't contain any card inside of it, i also add a checking that checks status of it, if it's `status = WFS_EXEE_IDC_MEDIAINSERTED`, i reset it(retain all cards) and after that call: `WFS_CMD_IDC_READ_RAW_DATA`. But again, i always get `WFS_EXEE_IDC_INVALIDMEDIA` event.

Comment: In ReadRawData command, you specify as input parameter the tracks/chip you want to read when the card will be inserted. Invalid Media error means that the card inserted has not got magnetic stripe or chip. If you execute the comand with a card inserted, that card inserted will be read. If no card is inserted, the device waits until the card will be inserted (because of this there are asyncronous functions). So, are you sure you are using a valid card to read with the tracks you want to read?

Answer (score 1):

Would be for the best if you could point what version of specitication you are using for CEN\XFS.

According to the document 4 of CEN\XFS specification version CWA15748:

**WFS_EXEE_IDC_INVALIDMEDIA:**
The user is attempting to insert the media in the wrong orientation. The card has not been
accepted into the device. The device is still ready to accept a card inserted in the correct orientation.

So, I would check:

1. Is everthing OK with the card you are using? Have you inserted the card in the correct way?
2. Is everthing OK with the card reader?
3. Is everything OK with that SP that you are using? I would probably ask support with the provider.

Besides, check the following: If your application can handle track data and chip data, make sure you are selecting the right flags in the lpwReadData.

Well, if someone needs more background information about cen\xfs development, I would suggest this Playlist: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3Sb2aDULGt5Wj6I4KJW526H8cd-vOvgG